# SQL Between Two Dates Missing End Date (SSRS)

Tags: sql, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I'm using SSRS 2008r2 to generate reports. Using following WHERE statement in SQL query

```
WHERE (NonPMJobs.npmJobCreateDate >= @Created_Parameter) AND     
      (NonPMJobs.npmJobCreateDate <= @Created_Parameter2)
```

I'm using parameters with the data type of `DateTime`. Users then select day from a calendar. I want to get results where jobs have been created between date 1 (`@Created_Parameter`) AND date 2 (`@Created_Parameter2`) INCLUSIVE.

But results being returned do not include the second date (`@Created_Parameter2`). If I select `01/07/2013 - 05/07/2013` I get 01, 02, 03, 04 but no 05. If I select 01/07/2013 - 06/07/2013 I get 01, 02, 03, 04, 05.

I've tried using:

```
WHERE (NonPMJobs.npmJobCreateDate BETWEEN @Created_Parameter AND @Created_Parameter2)
```

but get same results.

What am I missing here and why isn't `WHERE` statement inclusive? Any pointers would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, you need to think about this: a `DATETIME` like this: `05/07/2013` means the 5th of July (or 7th of May - depending on your locale) **at midnight when the day starts** (a 00:00 hours, so to speak).

So this does **NOT** include the events that happen on that day!

The best solution would be to use

```
WHERE (NonPMJobs.npmJobCreateDate >= @Created_Parameter) AND     
      (NonPMJobs.npmJobCreateDate < DATEADD(DAY, 1, @Created_Parameter2))
```

and basically getting everything that's smaller than the **next** day based on `@Created_Parameter2`. So for your 5th of July, that would be anything *before* the 6th of July - which includes **all** events from the 5th of July.

Comment: Genius. Thank you. I hadn't even considered 00:00. Have changed statement and it works. Thank you for your help.